# Java Xuggler Metadata List of Chapters MP4/M4V Video

Tags: java, ffmpeg, metadata, xuggler

I'm trying to use Xuggler like FFMPEG Metadata Wrapper (I just need the list of Chapters of MP4/M4V Video).

So far I have not been able to find a solution.
Can anyone help me?

I was only able to get the following information:

```
    final String filename = "...path...";
    IContainer container = IContainer.make();
    int result = container.open(filename, IContainer.Type.READ, null);
    if (result < 0)
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to open media file");
    int numStreams = container.getNumStreams();
    long duration = container.getDuration();
    long fileSize = container.getFileSize();
    long bitRate = container.getBitRate();
    System.out.println("Number of streams: " + numStreams);
    System.out.println("Duration (ms): " + duration);
    System.out.println("File Size (bytes): " + fileSize);
    System.out.println("Bit Rate: " + bitRate);
    for (int i = 0; i < numStreams; i++) {
        IStream stream = container.getStream(i);
        IStreamCoder coder = stream.getStreamCoder();
        System.out.println("*** Start of Stream Info ***");
        System.out.printf("stream %d: ", i);
        System.out.printf("type: %s; ", coder.getCodecType());
        System.out.printf("codec: %s; ", coder.getCodecID());
        System.out.printf("duration: %s; ", stream.getDuration());
        System.out.printf("start time: %s; ", container.getStartTime());
        System.out.printf("timebase: %d/%d; ", stream.getTimeBase().getNumerator(),
                stream.getTimeBase().getDenominator());
        System.out.printf("coder tb: %d/%d; ", coder.getTimeBase().getNumerator(),
                coder.getTimeBase().getDenominator());
        System.out.println();
        if (coder.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            System.out.printf("sample rate: %d; ", coder.getSampleRate());
            System.out.printf("channels: %d; ", coder.getChannels());
            System.out.printf("format: %s", coder.getSampleFormat());
        } else if (coder.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            System.out.printf("width: %d; ", coder.getWidth());
            System.out.printf("height: %d; ", coder.getHeight());
            System.out.printf("format: %s; ", coder.getPixelType());
            System.out.printf("frame-rate: %5.2f; ", coder.getFrameRate().getDouble());
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("*** End of Stream Info ***");
```

**UPDATE 07.06.2017**
I just tried it with VLCJ, but still I can not get the list of chapters.

```
    File file = new File("ia_ISL_13_r720P.m4v");

    NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "vlc64/");
    Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);

    MediaPlayerFactory mpf = new MediaPlayerFactory();
    EmbeddedMediaPlayer emp = mpf.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();

    MediaMeta mediaMeta = mpf.getMediaMeta(file.getAbsolutePath(), true);
    MediaMetaData asMediaMetaData = mediaMeta.asMediaMetaData();
    System.out.println(asMediaMetaData.getAlbum());
    System.out.println(asMediaMetaData.getArtist());
    System.out.println(asMediaMetaData.getTitle());

    emp.prepareMedia(file.getAbsolutePath());
    emp.play();
    emp.nextChapter(); // -> GO NEXT CHAPTER - SUCCESS

    List<List<String>> allChapterDescriptions = emp.getAllChapterDescriptions();

    for (List<String> list : allChapterDescriptions) {
        for (String string : list) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can anyone help you with what?
What is the exact problem with your code? Exceptions?
Please clarify your question!

Comment: I had written: (I just need the list of Chapters of MP4/M4V Video). The code contains no errors. Anyway I updated the post.

Comment: UPDATE 07.06.2017

Answer (score 0):

have you tested Mp4Chapters? Is for .net but is open source and maybe helps.

Am using it in a C# project I guess similar to what you are doing, very similar... 
Here am feeding a listbox with mp4 and m4v chapters, with old mp4 and m4v files seams to be working fine, but am having issues with new ones (2014 ->)

```
using Mp4Chapters;

// more code here...

private void readChapters(string inputFull)
{
            using (var str = File.OpenRead(this.inputFull))
            {
                var extractor = new ChapterExtractor(new StreamWrapper(str));
                extractor.Run();
                // build the listbox
                foreach (var c in extractor.Chapters ?? new ChapterInfo[0])
                {
                    this.lb_chapters.Items.Add(new { chapterTime = c.Time, chapterName = c.Name });
                }
            }
}
```

Other options is to parse the video file using ffmpeg and read the result:

ffmpeg -i ia_ISL_13_r720P.m4v -f ffmetadata metadata.txt

I hope this helps, let me know.
(sorry for the english, is not my main language)